# GRUB does not list Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 with a single root partition alongside Windows 10 in UEFI mode. The installer exits without errors, but GRUB does not list Ubuntu, only Windows 10.
Is there a way to boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: My system is a ThinkPad T14 with amd Ryzen Pro 4750G. This is my boot-info report https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f4ZxXHhHsv/

Also I had tried to repair with Boot-Repair before, but it somehow reinstalls kernel 5.4

Comment: Did it install the kernel. Normal fix is just an update-grub which just updates grub menu. But in advanced mode is total reinstall of grub and you can choose to install latest kernel. I would run the advanced options. Have you updated UEFI and NVMe firmware? That often is required. Do you have this setting?  Lenovo T460S unable to update firmware fwupdate disabled boot order lock
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455027